# Remove trailing ',' and extra spaces from string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use methods like replace, split, join, .... to canonicalize the string below to be the same as input?

Input:

```
"VS CODE,  ,  ,  JavaScript,  ,  ,  Hypertext Markup Language,  ,  ,  Cascading Style Sheets"
```

Output:

```
"VS CODE; JavaScript; Hypertext Markup Language; Cascading Style Sheets"
```

I tried to use methods like trim, split, join, replace but the result is still not as expected

Comment: Please edit your question to show input and desired output _as text_, not images. We can't copy and paste from images.

Comment: what is the string `input` and what you need as an `output`

Comment: How is that `input` created? Are you getting texts from HTML elements? If yes, you can probably change your querySelector to get the correct elements.

Comment: This is my first time on Stackoverflow, I apologize for the omissions and confusion. Thank you for your interest in my topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could solve it by splitting at ",", filtering out the empty values, and joining the result together.

```js
const input = "VS Code,  ,  ,  JavaScript,  ,  ,  Hypertext Markup Language,  ,  ,  Cascading Style Sheets"

const output = input
  .split(",") // split the input by ','
  .map(it => it.trim()) // in each item trim whitespaces
  .filter(it => !!it) // remove empty items
  .join("; "); // join them together
  
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple string methods:

1. Split string with ","
2. Filter for empty strings
3. Join array with ";"

```js
const input =
  "VS CODE,,, JavaScript,, , Hypertext Markup Language, ,, Cascading style sheets";
const result = input
                  .split(",")
                  .filter((s) => s !== "" && s !== " ")
                  .join(";");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use regular expressions to find and replace all your spaces & commas into ;

```js
const input = "VS CODE,  ,  ,  JavaScript,  ,  ,  Hypertext Markup Language,  ,  ,  Cascading Style Sheets"

console.log(
  input.replace(/[\s,]+[\s,]+/gm, '; ')
)
```

Comment: that will replace spaces inside the values also

Comment: `/[\s,]*,[\s,]*/gm` might work

Comment: @Nsevens you're right. I have modified the regular expression to only update when there is consecutive spaces & commas. Still, this expression doesn't clear out or modify trailing single comma or space into ;